# How to Parallel submit nested do loop

Tags: regions, parallelization, computational-geometry

This is the first time I'm trying to parallel compute something on Mathematica. So this question might be silly.
I have a nested Do loop of the form:

```
Do[Sb[i] = {}; 
 Do[If[RegionDimension[RegionIntersection[R[i], R[j]]] > 0, 
   Sb[i] = Union[Sb[i], {j}]], {j, i + 1, 25}], {i, 25}]
```

where `R[]` is a array of regions and I'm trying to find `RegionIntersection[]` among them and storing them in a array `Sb[]`.
Now when I try to evaluate using `ParallelDo` for the outer loop only, it is not working. Although it is easy to see it should work by dividing i=1 to 25 into n-parts for n-kernels, as each iteration of the outer loop is independent of each other.
Can you suggest me a way to parallel compute this?

An example:

```
In[40]:= Array[R, 8]

Out[40]= {ImplicitRegion[
  x[1] > 0 && x[2] > 0 && x[1] + x[2] < 1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[
  x[1] - x[2] > 0 && -x[2] > 0 && x[1] - 2 x[2] < 1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[
  x[1] > 0 && -x[2] > 0 && x[1] - x[2] < 1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[-x[1] + x[2] > 0 && -x[1] > 0 && -2 x[1] + x[2] < 
    1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[
  x[2] > 0 && -x[1] > 0 && -x[1] + x[2] < 1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[-x[2] > 0 && -x[1] + x[2] > 0 && -x[1] < 1, {x[1], 
   x[2]}], ImplicitRegion[-x[1] > 0 && 
   x[1] - x[2] > 0 && -x[2] < 1, {x[1], x[2]}], 
 ImplicitRegion[-x[1] > 0 && -x[2] > 0 && -x[1] - x[2] < 1, {x[1], 
   x[2]}]}
```

and output stored in Sb[] is

```
In[39]:= Array[Sb, 8]

Out[39]= {{}, {3, 7, 8}, {}, {5, 6, 8}, {}, {8}, {8}, {}}
```

Comment: There are basic syntax problems here: Sb[i] should be Sb[[i]] if Sb is an array - same for R[i], R[j]. Also you say you're storing intersections, but you appear to store lists {j}. And you're using RegionDimension, but shouldn't you use RegionMeasure?

Comment: @flinty. Yes, I don't store the intersection region but I store the label of each region that intersect. And Sb[] is an array in the sense that Sb[i] stores the list of all regions from j=i+1 to 25 that intersects with R[i]. Can you modify the code accordingly? and please don't assume 3D because sometimes I take R[i]'s to be an implicit region in 4D or higher D.

Comment: And I'm using RegionDimension to check if the intersection region is non-empty or not, as I only need to know that.

Comment: `RegionDimension[Point[{0, 0}]]` gives zero so it's possible the intersection is non-empty but has a well defined intersection. I'm assuming you are not considering points then?

Comment: No. The regions are well-defined bounded regions obtained from tetrahedron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think might be sort of a minimal fix to make your approach work.

I wasn't able to test this on the regions you provided but here's an outline of how I would do it, and it might work. If it doesn't work, you might try to fix it:

```
ParallelTable[
 If[
  RegionDimension[
    RegionIntersection[R[[i]], R[[j]]]
    ] > 0,
  j,
  Nothing
  ],
 {i, Length[R]},
 {j, i + 1, Length[R]}
 ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used a more functional approach here:

```
regions = {
   Disk[{0, 0}, 1],
   Disk[{5, 6}, 3],
   Disk[{2, 2}, 4],
   Disk[{58, 92}, 5],
   Disk[{-1, 1}, 2]
};
intersections = Select[
  ParallelMap[
   RegionIntersection @@ # &,
   Subsets[regions, {2}]]
 , RegionDimension[#] > 0 &];
```

If you don't want to store the regions themselves but instead store a list of pairs of positions in the list of regions that intersect with positive measure:

```
intersections = Map[
   {#[[All, 1]], RegionIntersection @@ (#[[All, 2]])} &,
   Subsets[
    MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1} &, regions]
   , {2}]];
Sb = Select[intersections, RegionDimension[#[[2]]] > 0 &][[All, 1]]
```

Another way to get the positions:

```
intersections = ParallelMap[
  If[RegionDimension[
      RegionIntersection[regions[[#[[1]]]], regions[[#[[2]]]]]
     ] > 0, #, Nothing] &,
  Subsets[Range[Length@regions], {2}]]
```

You can then `Scan` those pairs into your `Sb` like this

```
Clear[Sb];
Sb = ConstantArray[{}, 5];
Scan[AppendTo[Sb[[#[[1]]]], #[[2]]] &, intersections]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when I define regions=Array[R,25]; and run your code it is not giving the list of the intersection I want.

Comment: @SumitBanik I've added another method. Please give some more details on the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it is not exactly what I want. I have edited my question with an example of having 8 regions and the final Sb[i]. I exactly want that way but I want to parallel it and make it run faster

Comment: @SumitBanik Regrettably, it appears to me that what you really want is a consultant to do your work for you, and you are trying to get that done for free here. That's not how this site works. So, specify your question better for a start! flinty has already given you two possible solutions, but all you say is "that's not what I want". This site is not supposed to give you ready-made turn-key solutions all the time. Sometimes the best we can do is give you a pointer.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for your remarks. Sorry for the confusion with the question. I had the wrong notion that {} is a list and R[] is an array. 
Currently, I'm learning to code on Mathematica and often I search for hours and read several answers here and wolfram site. So when I see new commands and syntax I get confused and can not connect properly. Thus the "pointer" experts provide may not always be so for amateur/beginner.